# how do I limit the amount of data returned from a local json file

Tags: javascript, json

I want to fetch limited data from my local JSON. The code below retrieves everything.Any suggestions on how  I can limit the number of elements returned

```
fetch('data.json').then((data) => {
  return data.json();
}).then((completedata) => {
  console.log(completedata);
  let data = "";
});
})
```

Comment: You need server-side code for that.

Comment: As far as the server is concerned, it's just a text file. The server doesn't parse it so it can't tell where the elements are and how to filter to a certain number. You should define an API that returns what you want.

Comment: How many elements are returned and what is the total size in bytes?

Comment: 20 and I need 10

Comment: Do you want to limit the number of elements downloaded, or limit the number outputted when printed? Because the former has to be done on the server.